# Aquamacs, MacOS and language specific hotkeys

Tags: macos, emacs, language, input, aquamacs

I'm running Aquamacs on Mac OS Lion. Input mode is set to native.

When I switch input language to Russian all hotkeys stop working. As all keys are interpreted as Russian keys. Is there a simple way to make ^C work no matter which input language I have?

Switching to emacs input mode and changing emacs input language to Russian solves the problem, but then I can't use OS native language switching. And with three system languages it's a big problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following function, adapted from a [ru_emacs posting](http://ru-emacs.livejournal.com/82428.html):

```
(defun reverse-input-method (input-method)
  "Build the reverse mapping of single letters from INPUT-METHOD."
  (interactive
   (list (read-input-method-name "Use input method (default current): ")))
  (if (and input-method (symbolp input-method))
      (setq input-method (symbol-name input-method)))
  (let ((current current-input-method)
        (modifiers '(nil (control) (meta) (control meta))))
    (when input-method
      (activate-input-method input-method))
    (when (and current-input-method quail-keyboard-layout)
      (setq normal-local-function-key-map (copy-keymap local-function-key-map))
      (dolist (map (cdr (quail-map)))
        (let* ((to (car map))
               (from (quail-get-translation
                      (cadr map) (char-to-string to) 1)))
          (when (and (characterp from) (characterp to))
            (dolist (mod modifiers)
              (define-key local-function-key-map
                (vector (append mod (list from)))
                (vector (append mod (list to)))))))))
    (when input-method
      (activate-input-method current))))

(defadvice* ignore-reverse-input-method around (read-passwd quoted-insert)
  (let ((local-function-key-map normal-local-function-key-map))
    ad-do-it))

(reverse-input-method 'russian-computer)
```

Caveat: some previously unbound combinations in the English layout will also be remapped this way, e.g. `M-"` to `M-@`. As it does not extend to any already bound combinations, not much of a problem IMO.